# Listing down .netassembly names

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

How many assembles do we have in .NET 3.5? Can I list them down For eg: System; System.Windows.Forms and so on...Please help with code in C#

Comment: take a look at gac c:\windows\assemblies

Answer (score 3):

You can download the [.NET Framework 3.5 Common Namespaces and Types Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b645f3a-6d22-4548-a0d8-c2a27e1917f8&displaylang=en) on Microsoft's website.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick program to search `C:\Windows\assembly\` for all `.dll` assemblies and output the ones with a version of `3.5`:

```
// Get all "*.dll" files from "C:\Windows\assembly".
string windowsDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( "windir" );
string assemblyDirectory = Path.Combine( windowsDirectory, "assembly" );
string[] assemblyFiles = Directory.GetFiles(
  assemblyDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories
);

// Get version of each file (ignoring policy, integration, and design files).
var versionedFiles =
  from path in assemblyFiles
  let filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( path )
  where !filename.StartsWith( "policy" ) 
     && !filename.EndsWith( ".ni" ) 
     && !filename.EndsWith( ".Design" )
  let versionInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo( path )
  select new { Name = filename, Version = versionInfo.FileVersion };

// Select all 3.5 assemblies.
var assembliesIn3_5 = versionedFiles
  .Where( file => file.Version.StartsWith( "3.5" ) )
  .OrderBy( file => file.Name );

foreach( var file in assembliesIn3_5 )
  Console.WriteLine( "{0,-50} {1}", file.Name, file.Version );
```

Based on this PowerShell query:

```
dir C:\Windows\assembly -filter *.dll -recurse | 
  ? { [Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_.FullName).FileVersion.StartsWith('3.5.') } | 
  % { [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) } | 
  ? { -not $_.EndsWith('.ni') } | 
  sort
```

Also, you might find Hanselman's [Changes in the .NET BCL between 2.0 and 3.5](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangesInTheNETBCLBetween20And35.aspx) post useful.

Answer (score 0):

I need to display the list to my students..they are interested in seeing if it can be done and if we can list only the assembles(class names) of .net 3.5